# Drupal default search OR instead of AND

Tags: drupal, drupal-search

Is it possible to manipulate the **full** search term of Drupals default search engine? I want to make it an OR query without the user noticing it.

For example, if the user searches for

> bread butter

it should be changed into

> bread OR butter

right before passing it to the search_data() function. It know the hook_search_preprocess(), but hat function processes one word at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the [Advanced Search](https://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module or use Google Custom Search.
The [Google Custom Seach](https://drupal.org/project/google_cse) or the [Google Site Search](https://drupal.org/project/gss) module would be able to provide it, but you could choose for the manual integration too.